# Selenium: failing to find element by XPATH Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am a little bit new to programming but python really made get into it. I am trying to create a programm that automatically checks for updates in a website. I've successfully implemented the neccessary code to call the page of enrollment but yet there is one element that cannot be located. Since I have to do it for multiple courses and iterate throught them there is no specific id, I've tried to find it by title but also this didn't work.
Is there a way you can locate the button with the title "enroll".

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a\[@title ='enroll']").click()
```

but this didn't work and I always get

> NoSuchElement

error.

The XPATH for the button is simply: `//*\[@id="id572"\]`

Here is the part of the HTML code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot of HTML code you provided, the element is `<button>`, not `<a>`.

Try this xpath expression `//button[@title='enroll']`

Comment: it worked with driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='enroll']")

Comment: @cannik If in my work code, I prefer to use `button` rather than `*`. The more accurate the information, the better to locate the elements accurately.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if it's not in any iframes. Just grab the button whose title is enroll and click. Your css selector was an a tag and it might get id dynamically.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title ='enroll']").click()
```